# HTML input type file accept application/xml not working in chrome

Tags: html, browser

I have this simple HTML code

```
<input type="file" accept="application/xml"/>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPZevE

When I open the file selector popup from chrome, it does not filter the xml files, but when I run it in Firefox it filters well.

I have also tried `*.xml` which does not work either.

What is the reason behind this ?

Chrome version: 69.0.3497.100
OS Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows it will work.

It seems to be the interface between the OS and the browser, they are not understanding each others.

It's safer to use file extensions instead of mimetypes:

```
<input type="file" accept=".xml"/>
```

Comment: I think he should use accept="text/xml". Please elaborate why the extension should work better than the MIME type.